# how can i make this scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile-application

```
Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: isLoading
                        ? Center(
                            child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                          )
                        : GridView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            gridDelegate:
                                SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                              maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 60,
                            ),
                            children: List.generate(recipes.length, (index) {
                              return GridTile(
                                child: Tile(
                                  title: recipes[index].label,
                                  desc: recipes[index].source,
                                  imgurl: recipes[index].image,
                                  url: recipes[index].url,
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                          ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

would like to make this part `scrollable`
tried adding `singlechildscrollview` expanded `gridview` `girdview.builder` `listview` nothing works for me

tried many things nothing works for me i would like to make this part of my app `scrollable`  also it is `scrollable` on my laptop but i am not able to do it on my phone chat gpt says the problem might lies in the paraent widget so here's link to gist https://gist.github.com/AumRadia/ca9ae5336b7388df288181c97b73a01a you can check out full code

tried many things `singlechildscrollview`, `listview`,  `gridview`, `gridview.builde`r, expanded, flexible etc still not working.

Comment: Define "nothing works". Does it produce an error or does it just not work the way you expect? Also, don't debug your code with ChatGPT. It's a generative AI which means it's going to generate a response based on what it thinks is similar past queries, not any actual analysis of the code. For conversational contexts, this is convincing enough. For factual queries, it frequently gets things wrong, [sometimes with catastrophic results](https://www.reuters.com/legal/new-york-lawyers-sanctioned-using-fake-chatgpt-cases-legal-brief-2023-06-22/).